# Create New Objects vs Overwrite Existing Object (Performance)

Tags: c#, .net, performance, object, testing

I have to create a huge amount of slightly different objects for testing. All have their properties altered to be distinct object, but once I create the object & do something with it, I no longer need it.
**Should I create a new local object or, just overwrite & reassign the object that exists outside scope of the loop?**

**New (local) objects**

```
int testCases = 10;
for(int i=0; i<testCases; i++){
    TestObject localObject = new TestObject();  //local variable for the loop
    //change properties & do stuff with the test object
}
```

**Reassign/Overwrite Existing object**

```
TestObject myObject;
int testCases = 10;
for(int i=0; i<testCases; i++){
    myObject = new TestObject();    //reassign object that exists outside the loop
    //change properties & do stuff with the test object
}
```

The "change properties & do stuff" isn't that important, I know how to create the different versions of my object, just not sure if I should be destroying them each iteration.

Comment: You don't reassign the object, you create a new instance and assign that instance to the variable.

Comment: The new instances are created in both versions, so it doesn't really matter. If you do not use `myObject` outside the loop, then the compiler will optimize it away anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no functional difference between the two code snippets you posted. The allocation is happening on every loop iteration regardless of where you put the local variable in the code.

If you want to save on allocations, though, I can think of two possible solutions for you:

1. Use struct instead of class - This causes only stack space to be used instead of the heap. Only heap usage contributes to GC pressure. If you are passing around the struct a lot, though, you will need to pass by ref instead of by value to avoid the copying. Structs also "want" to be immutable, so you are a little restricted in how you use them, but not usually a big deal. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types) if you need to know more about structs/value types.
2. Use object reset/reuse semantics - instead of allocating a new object and filling it with data, just refill the same object with data over and over, without ever reallocating it. You essentially treat the object as a pooled object. Pooling can get complicated fast in non-trivial situations, but it's a good way to avoid additional memory pressure in some situations.

Comment: Oh, now I see that I am creating new objects both ways. I was confused about what saving the object to another variable would do